# Can I transfer photos from iPhone 4 to a MacBook via Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, bluetooth

Is there any way to transfer photos from the iPhone 4 camera roll to a MacBook over Bluetooth?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know you asked if it was possible over Bluetooth and although my research didn't turn up anything for non-jailbroken phones, here is a WiFi solution which you could use on an Ad-hoc network that would work effectively the same way.

### Non Jailbroken

- WiFi: [WiFi Photo Transfer (App Store)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-photo-transfer/id380326191?mt=8)
- iPhone to iPhone: [Bluetooth Photo Share (App Store)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bluetooth-photo-share/id326109583?mt=8)

### Jailbroken

- [iBlueNova](http://www.ihackintosh.com/2010/01/ibluenova-lets-iphone-users-send-and-receive-files-over-bluetooth/) (Cydia)

Comment: I'd recommend renaming to "iPhone to iPhone" because that app only transfer over bluetooth between iPhones, unlike the iBlueNova.